# Why does comparing an environment variable against undefined in Jest not work as expected?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, undefined, ts-jest

While implementing some tests in Jest to ensure that a required environment variable is defined, I ran into some strange behaviour when trying to compare the environment variable against `undefined`. `@types/node` seems to suggest that any specific environment variable is either `string | undefined`, however in practice it seems more complicated.

```js
  process.env.TEST_VAR = 'TEST';

  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR);    // TEST
  console.log(typeof process.env.TEST_VAR);    // string
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR === undefined);    // false
  console.log(!process.env.TEST_VAR);    // false
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR == undefined);    // false
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR === '');    // false

  process.env.TEST_VAR = '';

  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR);    // 
  console.log(typeof process.env.TEST_VAR);    // string
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR === undefined);    // false
  console.log(!process.env.TEST_VAR);    // true
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR == undefined);    // false
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR === '');    // true

  process.env.TEST_VAR = undefined;

  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR);    // undefined
  console.log(typeof process.env.TEST_VAR);    // string
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR === undefined);    // false
  console.log(!process.env.TEST_VAR);    // false
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR == undefined);    // false
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR === '');    // false
```

I know this might be pedantic, however in our particular use case there's a difference between the variable being *empty*, and the variable being *absent*. Running `node` on the command line, referencing any undefined environment variable actually returns `undefined`.
Does anyone know why this is occurring? And how would someone actually test for the difference between an undefined environment variable versus an empty one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it is defined:

```
interface Process extends EventEmitter {
  ...
  env: ProcessEnv;
  ...
}
interface ProcessEnv extends Dict<string> {
  TZ?: string;
}
interface Dict<T> {
  [key: string]: T | undefined;
}
```

Also in your test you got answer why you cannot compare the value with undefined.

```
  console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR);    // undefined
  console.log(typeof process.env.TEST_VAR);    // string
```

As even when you wanted to put `undefined` there, you actually put `'undefined'` instead.

Add this to your test

```
    delete process.env.TEST_VAR;
    
    console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR);    // undefined
    console.log(typeof process.env.TEST_VAR);    // undefined
    console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR === undefined);    // true
    console.log(!process.env.TEST_VAR);    // true
    console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR == undefined);    // true
    console.log(process.env.TEST_VAR === '');    // false
```

And this is how you set undefined value for environment variables